# UItextView delegate swift - textViewDidBeginEditing not called

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

I've seen the other topics dealing with `UITextView` delegate, but can't seem to find where my issue come from.
Here is my code, but when I modify my `UITextView`, nothing happens and `textViewDidBeginEditing` is not called.

```
import UIKit
var textView1 = UITextView()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView1.delegate = self
        textView1 = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:24,y: 100,width: 340,height: 290))
        textView1.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.00, blue: 0.00, alpha: 0.00)
        textView1.text = "textView 1"
        view.addSubview(textView1)
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("print1")
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) { 
        print("print2")
    }
}
```

I've tried with `UITextField`, but nothing changed, delegate functions still not called.

Comment: Why do you create and then throw away the first `UITextView` instance?

Comment: Why is `textView1` declared outside of the class? That's not what you should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a value from a nil object, you have to Initialize it and then you can set the target delegate.

Comment: Maybe because you are initializing twice.

Comment: Where have I a 2nd initialisation ? I tried to only keep 

    let textView1 = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:24,y: 100,width: 340,height: 290))

But it's the same.

Comment: I suggest you this:

        textView1.frame = CGRect(x:24,y: 100,width: 340,height: 290)
        textView1.delegate = self
        textView1.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.00, blue: 0.00, alpha: 0.00)
        textView1.text = "textView 1"
        view.addSubview(textView1)

Comment: oh then it's coming from me.. maybe because I've the 8.2 version.

Comment: I don't think so @VH24

Answer (score 3):

Just move your `textView1.delegate = self` 2 lines down. You are setting delegate for UITextField but in next line you are creating new object without any delegate ;)

Comment: Did not change anything :/

Answer (score 1):

[image]

please change the position of `textView1.delegate = self` with next line.

Comment: I change my code with yours then run the app. I change the text of textView1 but there is nothing printed in the output area..

It's surely something easy but I'm really stuck with this issue..

Comment: 1) Post actual code, not a picture. Pictures can't be referenced or searched. 2) How does this answer improve on the other, previous answers that already stated that the `textView1.delegate = self` line needs to be moved?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var textView1 = UITextView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView1 = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:24,y: 100,width: 340,height: 290))
        textView1.delegate = self
        
        textView1.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.00, blue: 0.00, alpha: 0.00)
        textView1.text = "textView 1"
        view.addSubview(textView1)
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("print1")
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) { 
        print("print2")
    }
}
```

Comment: "Please try" is not a useful description. Clearly explain what was wrong and how your answer solves the issue.

Comment: Problem solved after restarting my computer and changing the position of textView1.delegate = self with second next line.
There was also probably an issue with xcode like a bug, solved after the restart. thanks !